# UsageStatsManager method 'queryEvents' does not return more than one week old dates

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager, usageevents

```
UsageStatsManager manager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

UsageEvents events = manager.queryEvents(range[0], range[1]);
//range[0] is 25th April,2018 converted in long, and range[1] is May 25,2018 in long
```

The query returns event starting from May 18,2018, but I clearly added April 25th as the date. Is there any other way to retrieve the whole month usage stats?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. The docs for [UsageStatsManager.queryEvents()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#queryEvents(long,%20long)) say the following (emphasis mine):

> Query for events in the given time range. **Events are only kept by the system for a few days.**

To look back further in time, try [UsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#queryUsageStats(int,%20long,%20long)).